# How to retrieve key press/release event while GLFW window is in focus, but not process key event on the OS?

Tags: c++, keyboard, glfw, keyboard-events

With the Win32 API you can hook keyboard events at different stages in [this keyboard input model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/images/csinp-01.png)

If I was using the Win32 API, I could a create hook and retrieve the message from the system message queue, do "some stuff", then not send the message to the thread message queue. (I only want to cancel sending the message to the thread message queue if a a specific GLFW window is in focus)

But since I need my program to be cross platform, I'm just using a GLFW key callback to retrieve keyboard input when the GLFW window is in focus.

But if for example the user alt tabs (presses the Windows key on Windows, uses command + space on MacOS, etc.), I need to do "some stuff" with the keys they pressed without the user actually tabbing out of the GLFW window.

The only way the user should be able to drop focus of the GLFW window is if their cursor is out of the window's bounds and click out of it.

If the explanation of my problem is not so good, please let me know.